# Smarty - Output HTML Variables

Tags: php, html, string, variables, smarty

I cant understand how Smarty proceed with PHP string variables, with HTML tags:

If I type:

```
$string = '<b>Hello World</b>'

$smarty->assign('STRING',$string);
```

The result is **Hello World**

But if I type:

```
$string = getString(); // GetString returns "<b>Hello World</b>"

$output = "<div>".$string."</div>";

$smarty->assign('OUTPUT',$output);
```

The result is "< b >Hello World< /b >" literally, with HTML tags.

So, how can i get in this way, **Hello World** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked the below code and its showing same value
can u show me how you returning the value in getstring() function

```
$string = '<b>Hello World</b>';

$smarty->assign('STRING',$string);

function getString()
{
$val='<b>Hello World</b>';
$val=html_entity_decode($val, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  return $val;
}

$string = getString(); // GetString returns "<b>Hello World</b>"

$output = "<div>".$string."</div>";

$smarty->assign('OUTPUT',$output);
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere when I get the value from the database...

`code`function getString($id)
{
 global $adb;

 $sql = 'SELECT url FROM some_table WHERE id = '.$id;
 $result = $adb->query($sql);

 if($result)
 {
  $stringURL = $adb->query_result($result,0,'url');
 }

 return $stringURL;
}`code`

Comment: check with $val=html_entity_decode($val, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); where $val is the string value from database . i added in the code also..